# Why is wget not downloading newly added files from the server?

Tags: wget

I am running two virtual machines - say VM1 and VM2. Both are running Ubuntu 16.04 and VM2 has apache2 web server installed. Now in VM2 server, I have copied the code for a small website.

**PROBLEM:**

From VM1, I want to be able download the contents of the website using **`wget`** again and again at a set interval. Now it does download all website contents initially perfectly, but when I added a new file (a `.jpg` file, to the folder of website containing previous image files) to a folder (in website on the VM2 machine), and then I run wget command on the VM1 machine, the new file does **not** get downloaded.

**MY WGET COMMAND:**

`wget  --recursive  --convert-links  --no-check-certificate  --no-cache  --no-cookies  http://192.168.1.44/`

**WHAT I TRIED:**

So I thought it is a *caching* problem. But I already had `--no-cache` in my wget command, so I searched internet and executed the following command on server-side to clear apache2 cache. **But still no luck.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you added a JPEG image file but did not update any HTML file to include a reference to it (or a link to a dynamic index page) then Wget would not be able to find the JPEG.

Synchronising two sets of folders between machines would normally be done using tools such as rsync, robocopy etc that don't have this issue and which don't copy unchanged files and are therefore much much more efficient.

---

Update:

To look for changes to content on servers you don't have adminstrative access to, you can sometimes use the `HTTP HEAD` request and examine the `Last-Modified` header if present

```
C:\> curl --head https://www.gnu.org/graphics/heckert_gnu.transp.small.png
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 23:15:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (null)
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Nov 2016 18:01:39 GMT
ETag: "1dfd-541ab36d9a6c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7677
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 23:15:33 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Language: non-html
```

Wget has some options for using HTTP HEAD requests.

For a completely static website with no Javascript, you may be able to use a simple approach using Wget etc. I believe such sites are rare.

You will always have problems with dynamically generated pages. You would have to download and parse HTML from the site to determine the URLs you need to check. You may also need to execute Javascript.

You can only check for changes in generated content, not in the source files. As others have noted, generated content often has changes that are not of interest - such as timestamps, processing times, etc.

Comment: Also: `wget` will not have access to source files (such as PHP or Python files), but will only fetch their resulting HTML. So indeed `rsync` and all are the way to go.

Comment: @Arjan and OP - Thank you very much. I'll try it ASAP. My ultimate purpose is to find out if there is any change made to website i.e. any change to existing files and scripts or any new files added or deleted. I need to identify those changes and display them to my user. Something like [this tool](https://changetower.com/)

Comment: @Shy, do you/the user own the website that is to be monitored? (You wrote you copied source files, which suggests you have access to the server, rather than relying on the public output of said server.)

Comment: @Arjan Oh no. I have to monitor sites given by user. For speed of development and testing, I put my own website, i.e. source files, in another virtual machine (to act as server), and than associated that server VM's IP with a domain name in the hosts file in my client virtual machine, on which I am developing this monitoring tool. I did this all to speed up development process.

Comment: @Shy, then your answer is in the first sentence above, _"you added a JPEG image file but did not update any HTML file to include a reference to it"_, and you can forget about `rsync` and all. However, it's not going to be easy to use `wget` for what you want, as content might be the very same while the HTML returned to your browser is slightly different. Like if it includes sentences like "2 days ago" which will be "3 days ago" the next day, or debug details such as "generated in 200 ms", or worst: dynamic content that is loaded through JavaScript. And not each server/CMS will behave the same.

Comment: @Arjan You're right. Then what is your suggested way of doing this kinda thing?

Comment: @Shy: See updated answer.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick If a website defacement has occurred, I think it _will_ reflect in generated content, because why would someone attempt a defacement of a website if they don't wish to let the users know. Is that correct?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick (2) Now comes to my mind the case of a malicious redirect, but we can detect it from the html source code right?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick (3) And `--recursive` option of `wget` also downloads the  included JS and image files etc. So if we use the `--recursive` option of wget, won't that cover the problems of malicious redirects or otherwise injected code etc?